# Getop function negative numbers

Tags: c, calculator

I need to add provisions to negative numbers in my reverse Polish calculator program but getting this when testing the code:

**Input:**

```
-5 7 +
```

**Output:**

```
error: stack empty
error: stack empty
12
```

Here is the most relevant part of the code:

```
/* Getop: get next operator or numeric operand. */

  int getop (char s[]) {
      int i, c;
      while ((s[0] = c = getch()) == ' ' || c == '\t')
        ;
      s[1] = '\0';
      if  (!isdigit(c) && c!= '.' && c!= '-')  
          return c;                    /* Not a number */
      i = 0;

      if (c == '-') {

          if(isdigit(s[i]) || s[i] == '.') {

          c = s[i];          /* Copy c to s[i], first character of the                                
                         number */
           ++i;
         }

         else { 

             return c; 

         }

      }


      if (isdigit(c))        /*  collect integer part */
          while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
              ;
      if (c == '.')
          while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
              ;


      s[i] = '\0';
      if (c != EOF)
          ungetch(c);
      return NUMBER;
  }
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, so help will be appreciated.

edit by folks suggestion:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  /* for atof() */
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAXOP 100  /* max size of operand or operator */
#define NUMBER '0'  /* signal that a number was found */
#define MAXVAL 100  /* maximum depth of val stack */
#define BUFSIZE 100


int sp = 0;           /* next free stack position */
double val[MAXVAL];   /* value stack */  

int getop(char s[]);
void push(double);
double pop(void);
int pop_int(void);
int getch (void);
void ungetch(int);

/* reverse Polish calculator */

 int main()
 {

     int type;
     double op2;
     char s[MAXOP];

 while ((type = getop(s)) != EOF) {
     switch (type)  {

     case NUMBER:
          push (atof(s));
          break;

     case '+':

         push( pop() + pop() );
         break;


     case '*':

        push(pop() * pop());
        break;

     case '-':

     op2 = pop();                        /*   Addition on the real numbers is commutative because for any real numbers s,t, it is true that s+t=t+s.
                                           Addition and multiplication are commutative operations but subtraction and division are not. */
     push(pop() - op2);
     break;

     case '/':

     op2 = pop();
     if (op2 != 0.0)
         push(pop() / op2);

     else 
          printf("error: zero divisor\n");
     break;

     case '%':

     op2 = pop();

     push(fmod(pop(), op2));
     break;


      case '\n':

     printf("\t%.8g\n" , pop());
     break;

     default:
     printf("error: unknown command %s\n", s);
     break;

     }

   }
   return 0;

 }



 /* push : push f onto value stack */

 void push(double f)
 {
    if (sp < MAXVAL)    
        val[sp++] = f;

    else
        printf("error: stack full, can`t push %g\n", f);

 }



 /* pop: pop and return top value from stack */

  double pop(void)
  {

      if (sp > 0)
          return val[--sp];
      else {
          printf("error: stack empty\n");
          return 0.0;
      }

  }
```

Comment: For starters, you've commented out `++i`.

Comment: Where do those error messages come from? Don't you think it would be a good idea to show that part of the code at the very least? In fact, please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is `NUMBER`  that you return ?

Comment: NUMBER is defined as '0' macro

Comment: That's still not an MCVE. You do realise that you have not shown any code that calls `push` nor any code that calls `pop`? How do you expect anyone to find the problem? Please read the Stackoverflow help to learn how to write a good question.

Comment: `c = s[i]; /* Copy c to s[i], first character of the number */` You get this right ?    You are storing value of `s[i]` into `c` not copying `c to s[i]`.

Comment: How could I copy it?

Comment: `c` is int and `s` is char array .

Comment: s[ i ] = c then increment i

Comment: Still getting error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for getop:

```
int getop(char s[]) {
    int i, c;
    while ((s[0] = c = getch()) == ' ' || c == '\t')
        ;
    s[1] = '\0';
    if (!isdigit(c) && c != '.' && c != '-')
        return c;                    /* Not a number */
    i = 0;

    if (c == '-')
    {
        while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
    }

    if (isdigit(c))        /*  collect integer part */
        while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
        ;
    if (c == '.')
        while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
        ;


    s[i] = '\0';
    if (c != EOF)
        ungetch(c);
    return NUMBER;
}
```